# Sort and add data inside a file using a linux command

Tags: linux

I have the below data in my file

```
us-west-2b c3.xlarge 1
us-west-2b c3.xlarge 2
```

I need `us-west-2b c3.xlarge 3` as output . What is the linux command I can use ?

Here's a better example...

Source file contains

```
us-west-2a c3.large 2
us-west-2a c3.xlarge 2
us-west-2a m3.medium 8
us-west-2b c3.large 1
us-west-2b c3.xlarge 1
us-west-2b c3.xlarge 2
us-west-2b m3.medium 5
us-west-2c c3.xlarge 1
us-west-2c m3.medium 2
```

Desired Output is

```
us-west-2a c3.large 2
us-west-2a c3.xlarge 2
us-west-2a m3.medium 8
us-west-2b c3.large 1
us-west-2b c3.xlarge 3
us-west-2b m3.medium 5
us-west-2c c3.xlarge 1
us-west-2c m3.medium 2
```

Comment: "us-west-2b c3.xlarge 3" where is this line coming from? Can you elobrate your Question clearly?

Comment: us-west-2b c3.xlarge 3 is the output i am expecting

Comment: You already mention that in the question, but you should explain how to obtain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accumulate these with `awk`:

```
awk '{tot[$1" "$2] += $3} END{for (i in tot) { print i, tot[i]; } }' < data.txt
```

Here, the first two fields are stored as a key to an associative array `tot`, and the third field is added.  At the end, the total for each unique pairing of the first two fields is printed out.  The program expanded looks like:

```
{
    tot[$1" "$2] += $3
}
END {
    for (i in tot) {
        print i, tot[i];
    }
}
```

If you need to sort the result, you can always pipe the result through `sort` and specify whatever specific sorting criteria you need.

Example data.txt:

```
us-west-2a c3.large 2
us-west-2a c3.xlarge 2
us-west-2a m3.medium 8
us-west-2b c3.large 1
us-west-2b c3.xlarge 1
us-west-2b c3.xlarge 2
us-west-2b m3.medium 5
us-west-2c c3.xlarge 1
us-west-2c m3.medium 2
```

Result:

```
$ awk '{tot[$1" "$2] += $3} END{for (i in tot) { print i, tot[i]; } }' < data.txt | sort
us-west-2a c3.large 2
us-west-2a c3.xlarge 2
us-west-2a m3.medium 8
us-west-2b c3.large 1
us-west-2b c3.xlarge 3
us-west-2b m3.medium 5
us-west-2c c3.xlarge 1
us-west-2c m3.medium 2
```